# arcpy won't return correct data types of layers

Tags: arcpy, feature-layer

I wrote this so that arcpy would give me the data types for each of the layers in a map document. But, "Feature Layer" is the only type of data that is returned (apart from "N/A"). Shapefiles are shown as Feature layers as well. Any way to fix this?

```
import arcpy
path = 'D:/GIS/Location/'
er = path + "Tool 10_1 10_2.mxd"

mxd1 = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(er)
layers1 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd1)


for lyr in layers1:
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
        desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
        print "Name: " + lyr.longName + "...... " + "Type: " + desc.dataType
    else:
        print "Name: " + lyr.longName + "...... " + "Type: N/A"
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether you have solved this questions or not. I'll try to explain as far as I can understand your question: If you're try to get the filetype(or datatype) of the layer, other anwserers have make it very clear. Or, if you want to get the specific Geometry Type of the layer, may be you can try to use
`arcpy.Describe(source).shapetype` to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to fix, you are describing a *layer* object which will always return "FeatureLayer".

It actually says that in the help file under Layer properties (arcpy) in the summary section.

Not sure what you are trying to determine, the data source format (shapefile/geodatabase featureclass)? If that is the case if you get the `dataSource` property of the *layer* object you can search the string from the right for ".shp" that will confirm its a shapefile.

Answer (score 2):

This is because a feature layer created when a feature class is added to ArcMap's table of contents. `arcpy.mapping.ListLayers` lists these feature layers. You're interested in the source of the feature layers. Use something like (untested):

```
for lyr in layers1:
    try:
        source = layer.dataSource
        dType = arcpy.Describe (source).dataType
        print "Name: " + lyr.longName + "...... " + "Type: " + dType
    except:
        print "Name: " + lyr.longName + "...... " + "Type: N/A"
```